# Best way to modify an element that is not yet created

Tags: javascript

I have an `<input>` field in my web page, and I want to add a particular method on it, let say `fooBar()`.

Here is what I do:

```
<input id="xxx" .../>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("xxx").fooBar = function() { ... };
</script>
```

This works well. However, for some reasons I will not detail here (in fact the HTML is generated by JSF components), the `<script>` will be declared **before** the `<input>` tag.

So in others words, I will have that in my HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("xxx").fooBar = function() { ... };
</script>
<input id="xxx" .../>
```

So of course this code will not work correctly, as the script will try to get (`$("xxx")`) and modify an element that does not exist yet.

If I want to stick on the exact order of these two tags, what is the best way to accomplish what I want?

**Edit**

In my case, `$` refers to prototype, but I am also using `jQuery` in my application. And I must be compatible with IE6 :o(

Comment: `$` is what in your example? Prototype? jQuery?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I've edited my question for that. I use both of them, but here, `$` refers to Prototype.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to run your script after the document is loaded. With jQuery you'd do that with:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //do stuff here
});
```

I can't tell which library you're using here, but they all have an equivalent of jQuery's document ready.

Here's the prototype equivalent:

```
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
  // do stuff
});
```

Comment: In fact I wanted to do something more complicated, because in my real page, I have many `<input>` and then many `<script>` tags, each of them being specific (because the function `fooBar()` will do different thing, regarding the `<input>`). So now, I indeed execute X times the `$(document).ready()` method...

Comment: @romaintaz: You can put as much code in `$(document).ready()` as you want - there's no point calling it more than once.

Comment: @romaintaz: see update to my answer... instead of waiting for the entire document to load, each input element can have its own load listener.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting your code in `load` event:

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $("#xxx").fooBar = function() { ... };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If the code has to be directly before the input, you can check if it has loaded after a certain period of time.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Sets up a function to execute once the input is loaded
    f = function () 
        {
        //Checks if 'xxx' exists (may vary between frameworks)
        if ($("xxx") !== undefined) 
            {
            $("xxx").fooBar = function() { ... };
            //Escapes the timer function, preventing it from running again
            return true;
            }
        //If still not loaded check again in half a second (0.5s or 500ms)
        setTimeout(f,500);
        return false;
        }
    f();//Initialize the timer function
</script>
<input id="xxx" .../>
```

Comment: Clever, but what if this happens? `<script>(your script here)</script> <input id="xxx" .../> <script>$("xxx").fooBar()</script>` ... the call to fooBar in the second script could execute while the delayed loader is taking a half-second break...

Comment: I want to go with a setTimeout approach, but I didn't like it much. But in my case, the `fooBar()` can be executed only by `onchange` event of the `<input>`. So there almost no chance that the `fooBar()` method is fired within this 500ms...

Comment: you can reduce the time of the timer to something much more realistic such as 20ms, or 0.02 seconds... But yeah, it's definitely an ugly solution, I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding a method to the dom node, why not make it a separate function, so instead of

```
$("xxx").fooBar = function() {
  doStuff(this); 
};
```

you would have something like

```
function xxx_fooBar () {
  var me = document.getElementById('xxx');
  doStuff(me);
};
```

---

Another suggestion: If you can add attributes to the `<input>` element, you could do something like this...

```
<script>
function xxx_init (e) {
  e.fooBar = function () {
    doStuff(this); 
  };
} 
</script>
<input onload="xxx_init(this)" id="xxx" .../>
```

---

Or you could do as others suggest and attach the scripts to the window.onload event.

Comment: I don't understand how this approach could solve my issue. In such case, I would need to call all my `xxx_fooBar()` methods when the document is ready...

Comment: is fooBar really an event listener, like `onchange`? In that case, this won't help you at all. I was assuming `fooBar` was just a generic function property, not an event listener. In that case you could just call `xxx_fooBar()` instead of `$("xxx").fooBar()`. If `fooBar` is really `onchange` or `onclick` or something, no, this won't work.

Comment: @no `fooBar()` is just a function, called by `onchange` event indeed, but also by another Javascript method. But when it is called by `onchange`, it must call `myElement.fooBar();` and not `myElement_fooBar();`. But ok, now I get your idea.